# How to convert MNIST data to be able to use MLPClassifier?

Tags: python, neural-network, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to edit a given machine learning code that runs 3 different training networks. The goal is to use the `MLPClassifier` from scikit-learn. The error I keep receiving is that I am setting an array element with a sequence. I understand that  the data are tuples, but am not sure how to change it to be able to use the classifier. I am new to python and trying to understand arrays and matrixs currently. This is what I have so far. The error comes from the last line, would I have to split the data differently or convert it to a non tuple? Any advice would be great!

```
# To support both python 2 and python 3
from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals

# Common imports
import numpy as np
import os

# Standard library
import random

# to make this notebook's output stable across runs
np.random.seed(42)

# To plot pretty figures
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 14
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 12
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 12

# Where to save the figures
PROJECT_ROOT_DIR = "."
CHAPTER_ID = "classification"

def save_fig(fig_id, tight_layout=True):
    path = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_DIR, "images", CHAPTER_ID, fig_id + ".png")
    print("Saving figure", fig_id)
    if tight_layout:
        plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(path, format='png', dpi=300)

#import and split the dataset  
import mnist_loader
training_data, validation_data, test_data = map(list,mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper())
training_data = list(training_data)

print(len(training_data))

#Setting up and training 1st network
import network
net1 = network.Network([784, 30, 10])
epochs = 30
mini_batch_size = 10
eta = 3.0
net1.SGD(training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta, test_data=test_data)

#Second Network
import network
net2 = network.Network([784, 100, 10])
epochs = 30
mini_batch_size = 10
eta = 3.0
net2.SGD(training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta, test_data=test_data)

#3rd Network    
import network
net3 = network.Network([784, 10])
epochs = 30
mini_batch_size = 10
eta = 3.0
net3.SGD(training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta, test_data=test_data)

#Use Classification Built-in Neural Network from Scikit-Learn

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
mlp= MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100,),activation='logistic',solver='sgd',batch_size=10,max_iter=30,learning_rate_init=3,learning_rate='constant')
mlp.fit(training_data,test_data)
```

Comment: Is `test_data` the labels (i.e. target values)?

Comment: Yes the test_data and training data are a split of the mnist data (from what I understand)

Comment: @Julia That clears up a lot of the confusion ! Thank you very much for the link!

Comment: Exactly. `training_data` contains both, x and y. In `mlp.fit()` you need to provide x and y separately from the `training_data`. `test_data` is for testing your model performance. You need to check what is a type of your `training_data` and how to separate x from y.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment with the link. Here https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/mnist_loader.py it explains how `mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper()` works.

Comment: @Julia just to clarify, I would need to alter the mnist_loader code to have it select the separate x and y values and?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation provided for `mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper()` (https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/mnist_loader.py), it returns `training_data` in the form of tuples per each sample (input + label), where input is a 784-dimensional array and the label is a 10-dimensional array. The reason for such a format is given as

> the format is more convenient for use in our implementation of neural networks.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find an example use of this function in the documentation. You might consider using the `load_data()` function instead:

```
training_data, validation_data, test_data = mnist_loader.load_data()
x_train, y_train = training_data[0], training_data[1]
```

The data is already normalized, so you should be able to use in your fit function right away:

```
mlp.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

As an alternative, you could load the data from tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
```

Unless there is a reason why you want to use `mnist_loader`.

Comment: So for this project we have to use mnist_loader (basically copying what that github uses) I found a way to get the data to split properly for the training data using reshape because the tuple has 3 variables and I need it to be 2, basically combining the last 2 columns (784,1) which allows me to fit() the two variables (my case training_data_img, training_data_label)